# What's a functional alternative to nested Do loops?

Tags: functional-style, iteration

How can I use functional code to achieve the same effect as the following procedural code

```
Do[
    Do[
        f[i,j],
        {j,1,m}
      ],
    {i,1,n}
   ]
```

Comment: There's the unnested `Do[f[i, j], {i, n}, {j, m}]`, which is almost as fast as `Array` and `Outer` (faster if `m*n` is very large) and quite a bit faster than `Apple` or `Scan`. And `Do` uses very little memory. -- Now, my understanding is that in functional programming, one generally aims for functions to have no side effects, in which case, `Null` seems the most efficient to accomplish the above. :) In other words, looking for functional code to accomplish a non-functional task seems odd.

Comment: `Scan` might be useful in this setting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Defining a function with some side-effect for demonstration purposes.

```
f[i_, j_] := Echo[{i, j}]
```

Here are some more WL-esque options:

- [`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html)

```
Array[f, {2, 3}];
```

- [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html)

```
Outer[f, Range[2], Range[3], 1];
```

- [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)

```
f @@@ Tuples[{Range[2], Range[3]}];
```

Note the `;` above to suppress the output. If your function indeed only has side-effects and you don't want the output (supposedly that's why you chose [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) instead of [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)), you can also use [`Scan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html):

```
Scan[Echo, Tuples[{Range[2], Range[3]}]]
```